# Change timer interval from another form via radio buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, radio-button

I have a public timer1 on Form1 and some radio buttons on Form2. How do I change the timer interval of timer1 on Form1 by clicking on a radio button on Form2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a public int property `myInt`on form2 whose value is set by choosing a radio button, then on form1 do this:

```
using (Form2 f2 = new Form2())
{
    f2.ShowDialog();
    timer1.Interval = f2.myInt;
}
```

*this is from memory so it's not tested, but the general idea is the same

Alternatively, you can pass timer1 to form2 by reference by changing the form2 constructor from

```
public Form2()
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
public Form2(Timer t1)
{
    this.myTimer1 = t1;
}
```

and add the property on form2:

```
private Timer myTimer;
```

Then in form1 you would do

```
using(Form2 f2 = new Form2(timer1))
{
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then you can change your timer1 settings immediately when making changes in form2, whereas in my earlier answer the changes only take place after the form closes. Which ever way you want to do it depends on the needs of your application.

Comment: His question was how to use the radio buttons to change the interval. Even if he was trying to do something else with the timer, the general idea of querying a public property on form2 still applies. However, if you were to argue that he has more functionality if he passes the timer by reference, then I would agree with you, and that's actually a better way to do it. But this seemed to work for his purposes. Nonetheless, I'll include the code for passing the timer by value.